# How do you compare classes for order?

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I am having issues finding an efficient way to sort classes by order. My following code completes the order in which i need to sort, but I believe there is another way (one I dont know).

What is an efficient way to sort classes?

```
public int compare(Object one, Object two)    
{  
          //S = Salaried, W = Weekly, D = Daily

          //SS == 0 -> SW == -1 -> SD == -1
          //WS == 1 -> WW == 0 -> WD == -1 
          //DS == 1 -> DW == 1 -> DD == 0

          Employee a = (Employee)one;
          Employee b = (Employee)two;

          SalariedEmployee s = new SalariedEmployee(0.0); 
          WeeklyEmployee w = new WeeklyEmployee (0.0);
          DailyEmployee d = new DailyEmployee();


          if(one.getClass() == s.getClass() && two.getClass() == s.getClass())
              return Double.compare(b.grossPay(), a.grossPay());

          if(one.getClass() == s.getClass() && two.getClass() == w.getClass())
              return -1;

          if(one.getClass() == s.getClass() && two.getClass() == d.getClass())
              return -1;

          if(one.getClass() == w.getClass() && two.getClass() == s.getClass())
              return 1;

          if(one.getClass() == w.getClass() && two.getClass() == w.getClass())
              return Double.compare(b.grossPay(), a.grossPay());

          if(one.getClass() == w.getClass() && two.getClass() == d.getClass())
              return -1;

          if(one.getClass() == d.getClass() && two.getClass() == s.getClass())
              return 1;

          if(one.getClass() == d.getClass() && two.getClass() == w.getClass())
              return 1;

          if(one.getClass() == d.getClass() && two.getClass() == d.getClass())
              return Double.compare(b.grossPay(), a.grossPay());

          return 0;

      }
```

Comment: The sorting order is 
SalaryEmployee -> WeeklyEmployee -> DailyEmployee as first Key
grossPay as second key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having issues finding an efficient way to sort classes by order

Depends what you mean by "efficient". Putting all the code in a single method will be the most efficient (if done properly) from a CPU perspective, but it is not very efficient from a flexibility point of view.

For an approach that will not be a fast but will be far more flexible check out the [Group Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/) and [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/).

The GroupComparator allows you to combine multiple Comparators into one sort. The BeanComparator is a generic comparator that allows you to sort on any field within a given class. So to use the GroupComparator the basic code would be:

```
EmployeeComparator employee = new EmployeeComparator();
BeanComparator grossPay = new BeanComparator(Employee.class, "grossPay");
GroupComparator gc = new GroupComparator(employee, grossPay);
Collections.sort(list, gc);
```

So you would need to write a Comparator that sorts Employees by salaried, weekly and daily. The basic code for the EmployeeComparator might be something like:

```
if (one.getClass()equals(two.getClass())
    return 0;

if (one instanceOf SalariedEmployee)
    return 1;

if (two instanceOf SalariedEmployee)
   return -1;

if (one instanceOf WeeklyEmployee)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

A little more work to set up, but once you have an EmployeeComparator you can then sort of multiple different properties using the Bean and Group Comparators.

Answer (score 3):

implement Comparable<> interface in your class and override `compareTo()` method in Employee class. the method takes Object class as a passed value. For example,

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    //omitted

    public int compareTo(Employee other) {
        return grossPay.compareTo(other.grossPay);
    }
}
```

check out the following link to learn more
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: I appreciate your response, however this only solves my grossPay issue, not the class order. So basically there are two orders Salary -> weekly -> Daily classes and then gross pay. 
for Example Salary 500 Weekly 550 Daily 450.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
public int compare(Employee left, Employee right) {
    int typeOrderLeft = getTypeOrder(left);
    int typeOrderRight = getTypeOrder(right);

    if (typeOrderLeft == typeOrderRight) {
        return Double.compare(left.grossPay(), right.grossPay());
    } else {
        return typeOrderLeft - typeOrderRight;
    }
}

private int getTypeOrder(Employee employee) {
    if (employee instanceof DailyEmployee) {
        return 1;
    } else if (employee instanceof WeeklyEmployee) {
        return 2;
    } else if (employee instanceof SalaryEmployee) {
        return 3;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first implement the comparable interface. This lets you define a compareTo method which can be used to sort classes based on a specificed value that you think is viable for comparing classes.

Defining the compareTo method is useful for objects that don't have a predefined way of comparing themselves.